# Вывод категорий на странице архива

Tags: wordpress

Создал custom post type и добавил к нему taxonomy. 
На данной странице выводятся все посты, которые относятся к этому post-type. 
Подскажите, как вывести на странице archive-{custom-post-type}.php сначала список всех категорий (таксономии), при переходе на который вижу все посты.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть будет кому-то полезно.

```
    <?php 
        $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'your_post_type'
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'your_taxonomy') . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
?>
```

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata()` должен стоять вне `if`. Ему в любом случае надо отработать.. https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_reset_postdata

Comment: А для `get_terms` можно добавить параметр `hide_empty`, чтобы не проверять потом всё на наличие записей. https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms#hide_empty-logicheskij

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, спасибо, исправил.